# Can I use a variable to slice my list in Python?

Tags: python, variables, slice

I am trying to write a code that takes the middle of the list and REMOVES the middle index element and the next index element from the list and put it in a new list.

```
def odd_indices(lst):
  x = len(lst)/2
  new_lst = lst[:x] + lst[x-1:]
  return new_lst
  
print(odd_indices([4, 3, 7, 10, 11, -2]))
```

(I am trying to remove "7" and "10" from the list)

In theory, the output should be

```
[4, 3, 11, -2]
```

but that is not the case as instead I get an error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(odd_indices([4, 3, 7, 10, 11, -2]))
  File "script.py", line 5, in odd_indices
    new_lst = lst[:x] + lst[x-1:]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

I believe that this error is caused due to me using a variable in a slice.

Please let me know what the fix to it is!

Comment: use `//` to divide. you're getting a float, which you can't use to index

Comment: you can definitely use a variable to slice a list in python

Comment: oh gotchu, but it now prints out this and not what i want:

 [4, 3, 7, 7, 10, 11, -2]

Comment: `x-1` should be `x+2`

Comment: `lst[:x]` should be `lst[:x-1]` so you don't include the middle element.

Comment: You'd have to do `lst[:x-1] + lst[x+1:]` for that, though that wasn't initially part of your question.

Comment: got it to work, final code looks something like this:

def odd_indices(lst):
  x = len(lst)//2
  new_lst = lst[:x-1] + lst[x+1:]
  return new_lst
print(odd_indices([4, 3, 7, 10, 11, -2]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but that's not the issue. `x` is not an int here, it's a float. Whenever you use `/`, the result will always be a float. You can use floor division to get around that. Instead of `len(lst) / 2`, use `len(lst) // 2`. Also, unrelated to your question, but change `lst[x-1:]` to `lst[x+1:]` to get the desired effect.